# ECS instance dies periodically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Thanks to click my question.
I'm running my server with Amazon ECS.
But there is a problem that my EC2 Instance dies periodically.

Let me explain my ECS set up first.
I have one `REPLICA` type service, running two Task on it with same Task Definition.
[Cluster services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCF99.jpg) | [Configure service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYN41.png) | [Cluster tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USs1G.jpg)
And i'm running ECS Instance with t2-micro EC2 Instance whose vCPU is 1, RAM is 1GiB.
I assign 512 unit CPU, 350 MiB Memory for task size, and there is no Hard/Soft memory limits for container.
[ECS Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCdBV.jpg) | [Task size of Task Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKkOn.jpg)

And please have a look at this [Memory Utilization metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5DFV.jpg) on CloudWatch.
This is my cluster's metric of Memory Utilization.
As you can see, every time it hits almost 60%, the graph is cut or dropped.
The way that i wish my containers run is, if one of two container hits its memory limit, it restarted while other container works well.
I think the graph dropped part works in a way that i wish for.
But occasionally graph is cut and in that period, EC2 Instance has been died and after about 20-60 mins, it restarted.
Here is the logs when graph is cut.

```
2021-10-31 22:28:20 +0900
service ~ has started 1 tasks: task 09c758f5453d4c8db36e82dd69fd92b9.
3152b3c2-2227-44e8-9512-2b5615abcbcd
2021-10-31 22:28:10 +0900
service ~ has started 1 tasks: task 57ce102a173940cab27d2b09bcdbdf42.
c82a1621-7fc6-43df-88ac-e74e92243512
2021-10-31 22:04:10 +0900
service ~ has stopped 2 running tasks: task e11779a50c934034a0e2ff435a93da9f task 2e4fb68f6b044e93b8eb99c3e3e17586.
302ab09c-f14e-4c5d-93e7-03beafc3b946
2021-10-31 22:04:10 +0900
service ~ deregistered 2 targets in target-group ~-target-group
a14c5b34-cf63-47b9-b687-68a385013521
2021-10-31 22:04:10 +0900
service ~ (instance i-023501ac25dd6a682) (port 32773) is unhealthy in target-group ~-target-group due to (reason Request timed out)
c039e787-5f0a-4fcd-bea3-fc7045ef9f87
2021-10-31 22:04:10 +0900
service ~ (instance i-023501ac25dd6a682) (port 32772) is unhealthy in target-group ~-target-group due to (reason Request timed out)
```

I suspect this is because some sort of `out of memory` problem, but i'm not sure why exactly this happens.
Could anyone help me not to make my instance die?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check with t2.medium?

Comment: No i didn't, because i'm running my server only with t2 micro free tier.

Comment: So put hard limits. Your containers may be taking too much ram.

Comment: You mean, put hard limit on container and remain task memory size?

Comment: yes. Its better to kill your task, then ec2 instance.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try.
And it would take some days to check whether how it works on memory limit case.

Comment: Let me know how it will go. If it works, I can provide an answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping me ! Have a good day.

Comment: `i'm running my server only with t2 micro free tier' I suggest to see how the container behaves on the larger instance. Just consider what costs more - your time to investigate or a few cents to try out. Or at least set a soft mem limit to see the logs if the limit is crossed.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try to make another t2 small ecs instance and launch same tasks with same config, and take a look metric for several days. Thanks for suggestion.
Btw, what does that mean 'limit is crossed'?

Comment: @Marcin Ok, i got a result earlier than i expected. And the instance stopped again. At this time, instance had stopped more than 3 hours which didn't happened before. So while instance is stopped i check several evidence. First of all, instance on EC2 console looks perfectly fine. Instance state was `Running` and both system and instance status checks were fine. Second, i can't connect to instance with SSH, which is the thing i could always did. Third, metric on ECS was cut for 3 hours like always did.

Comment: So i just stopped the ec2 instance, and another ec2 instance has made automatically.

Comment: Your instances is running without resources, you need to upgrade to a major instance type, the performance of t2.micro is not good for a service with these resource reservations. What about the CPU, in one image the CPU available is 0, everything was reserved.